# How do I correctly copy given range of vector to another vector using std::copy?

Tags: c++98, mbed

I found a few pages on moving vector range to another vector, however I am struggling to make it work.

I would like to move elements from `sourceVect` to `destVect`, with the elements between `sourceVect[1]` to `sourceVect[1+numToCopy]` being moved to the beginning of sourceVect. I tried to do this in the following way:

```
vector<int> destVect;
vector<int> sourceVect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
int numToCopy = 7;

vector<int>::iterator itSource = sourceVect.begin();
vector<int>::iterator itSourceEnd = sourceVect.begin();
advance(itSource, 1);
advance(itSourceEnd, 1+numToCopy);

std::copy(itSource, itSourceEnd, destVect.begin());             //copy(first,last,output vector ite)


for (vector<int>::iterator it = destVect.begin(); it != destVect.end(); ++it)
    cout << ' ' << *it;
```

But I am getting Debug Assertion Failed, vector iterator + offset out of range in Visual studio. Please note that I am only trying it out in Visual Studio 2015, it has to be implemented in C++98 for mbed at the end, meaning I can't use `std::next` for example.

Comment: Note that you can use C++11 with Mbed OS through a custom [build profile](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/tools/build-profiles.html) where you can set `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::copy()` will not create new elements in the destination container. That means you need to create `destVect` with the correct size:

```
vector<int> sourceVect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
vector<int> destVect(sourceVect.size() - 1);
```

If you can't create it with the correct size, just resize it later on, at the point where you know the size:

```
destVect.resize(sourceVect.size() - 1);
```

You can now copy:

```
copy(sourceVect.begin() + 1, sourceVect.end(), destVect.begin());
```

However, you can just create `destVect` with the correct contents to begin with. You don't need to manually copy anything:

```
vector<int> sourceVect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
vector<int> destVect(sourceVect.begin() + 1, sourceVect.end());
```

This is the fastest way to do this and (perhaps more importantly) it's not prone to errors. If you do an `std::copy` but your destination container's size is not large enough, you end up writing into non-allocated memory (buffer overflow.)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't initialise it with the correct size. At least now I know what the problem is, ill try to get around it by setting the memory beforehand I guess.

Comment: @TrybGhost In that case, just use `resize()`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`vector::iterator` has always supported `+`, you don't need `next` or `advance`. The simplest way is to initialise from a pair of iterators.

```
 std::vector<int> sourceVect = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
 std::vector<int>::iterator first = sourceVect.begin() + 1;
 std::vector<int>::iterator last = first + numToCopy;
 std::vector<int> destVect(first, last); // contains 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

If you can't avoid delaying declaring `destVect` to the point where you have an appropriate initialiser, you can use `assign`

```
 destVect.assign(first, last); // contains 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 overwriting whatever was there before
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::back_inserter from <iterator>

```
std::copy(sourceVect.begin() + 1, sourceVect.begin() + 1 + numToCopy, std::back_inserter(destVect));
```

This basically just does a push_back inside destVect.